# solving a linear recurrence relationship involving trig

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

can anyone gave me some idea of how to solve $a_{n+2}-2\cos(\theta)a_{n+1}+a_n=0$ ? I am not sure how to perform a calculation to this three term recurrence-- I know I can solve a two term recurrence but a characteristic polynomial but I really have no idea how to do this-- some help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $z^2-(2\cos\theta)z+1$.  Its zeros are $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: thank you! just discovered that this is indeed characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by GEdgar, the characteristic polynomial is
$$ z^2 - 2 \cos(\theta)z + 1  \text{.}  $$
It's worth pointing out that "$\cos \theta$" is just some constant, so you could replace it with some parameter and ignore its trigonometry-ness.
The characteristic polynomial factors as 
$$  (z - (\cos \theta + \mathrm{i} \sin \theta))(z - (\cos \theta - \mathrm{i} \sin \theta))  \text{,}  $$
so the general solution to the recurrence is 
$$ C_1(\cos \theta + \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)^n + C_2(\cos \theta - \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)^n  \text{.}  $$

We use the fact(s):
$$ 1 = \cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = (\cos \theta + \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)(\cos \theta - \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: wait but isnt there three terms-- I am somehow confused now.

Comment: also is there a way to compute c1 and c2 if we do not know what a0 is?

Comment: @M.Chen : We have the general solution.  Since you have a three term recurrence, we need to know (usually, the first) two terms to get a particular solution.  From any two $a_i, a_j$, you can find $C_1$ and $C_2$ from  $$C_1(\cos \theta + \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)^i + C_2(\cos \theta - \mathrm{i} \sin \theta)^i = a_i$$ and the analogous equation for $a_j$.  (This is straightforward algebra since these are linear equations.)